# How to remove name that added to a file?

Tags: java, encryption

I'm reading a file name and encrypt it, and save back with additional name

```
FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("cv-resume.pdf");
//encrypt
FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("cv-resume.pdf"+".enc");
```

After I decrypt back I want to remove the ".enc" to get back original file name. Any idea how to do this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: you mean , you want to rename `cv-resume.pdf.enc` back to `cv-resume.pdf` ? Can't you user `File` `rename` API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
FileOutputStream inFileEncrypt = new FileInputStream("cv-resume.pdf.enc");
//Decrypt
FileOutputStream outFileDecrypt = new FileOutputStream("cv-resume.pdf");
```